# django при нажатии на кнопку edit выдаёт ошибку Page not found (404)

Tags: python, django

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/todos/%7Burl%20'edit'%7D
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^todos/ ^$ [name='index']
^todos/ ^add [name='add']
^todos/ ^details/(?P<id>\w{0,50})/$
^todos/ ^edit/(?P<id>\d+)$
^todos/ ^delete/(?P<id>\d+)$
^admin/
The current URL, todos/{url 'edit'}, didn't match any of these.
```

при этом в todos/urls.py прописано:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^add', views.add, name='add'),
    url(r'^details/(?P<id>\w{0,50})/$', views.details),    
    url(r'^edit/(?P<id>\d+)$', views.edit),
    url(r'^delete/(?P<id>\d+)$', views.delete)
]
```

в details переходит, add тоже никаих проблем, в чем ошибка? все def прописані во views.py принадлжеать одному классу Todo. Как?

Comment: URL, который начинается с edit, ожидает получить от одного и более цифр после слэша, а получает `%7Burl%20'edit'%7D`. Проверяйте шаблон, смотрите откуда у вас в `href` попадает эта ересь.

Comment: ооо, точно, спасибо